# How to get the Values of Selected Row from a Gridview in TextBox on another page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, textbox, grid

i am able to get the selected value in textbox which is on same page but now I want that selected coloumn to be displayed in textbox of another page.
Please help.

Comment: The question needs more detail. Do you use master page as master page is common to motre than one page. If you are not using master page then you can use querystring to send data from one page to other. Also you can use session but session is not suggested as this will be server overloading.

Comment: I think it is possible with the help of sessions.

now look i have two pages. On "page1.aspx" i have a button onclick grid pops up. that grid is on "page2.aspx"

it popup using iframes. Now what i want is to select particular column and that column should be displayed in textbox which is on page1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment below are some links which may help you in passing the data from iframe to page1.

[Set variable in parent window from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301540/set-variable-in-parent-window-from-iframe)

[How can I pass attribute value from iframe to parent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381920/how-can-i-pass-attribute-value-from-iframe-to-parent-in-javascript)

[How pass data to parent window from iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243575/how-pass-data-to-parent-window-from-iframe)